# New Laravel project, /login is forbidden

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

There are a couple of questions like this, but none of them worked for me.

I have a new project in Laravel. I created new `/register` route, works perfectly.
But `/login` is not working. I'm getting `403 Forbidden` error and `nginx/1.13.3` beneath. I tried adding new `.htaccess` file in the root of the project and it didn't work.
I have a project that I created couple of months ago, with the same route `/login` and it still works perfectly, with no `.htaccess` fine in root.

I'm using `Homestead` machine as the server and I have `Laravel 5.6.1`. project.

And, no matter what I do, the same error is still there. I can remove the route, the controller or the view (just to provoke new, familiar error) but still the same one.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a Homestead related issue.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on because the project on which it works is on the same Homestead.

Comment: Try installing Laravel 5.5 instead of 5.6

Comment: You'd better describe Sentinel problem, not laravel auth. Why do you mention it only as comments below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [nginx doesn't need an `.htaccess` file](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/). It exists for apache users in new Laravel projects.

Second, Laravel has the authentication routes builtin, you shouldn't need to create `login` and `register` routes. Run:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

to scaffold your auth routes and views. Try removing the `/register` route you created and run the above command.

Comment: Because I'm using Sentinel instead of Laravel Auth.

Comment: I don't need Auth, I need those routs for Cartalyst Sentinel auth package, that I'm using. I used it before, and never had this error.

Comment: Those are the kind of details that should be in the original question.

Comment: Sorry for that.

Comment: The problem was overlapping folder name in public folder. I messed with dynamic folder creation that I used for the site. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
     php artisan make:auth
```

and

```
    php artisan migrate
```

in a fresh Laravel application.

Then, navigate your browser to

```
    http://your-app.dev/register
```

or any other URL that is assigned to your application. These two commands will take care of scaffolding your entire authentication system!